# Why is File::Spec dropping './' on files in sub directories?

Tags: pathname, perl, file-find

[`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec) is a core module to *"portably perform operations on file names"*. This behavior makes perfect sense to me,

```
# returns ./foo
File::Spec->catfile(".", "foo");
```

However, this has my mind boggled.

```
# returns foo/bar
File::Spec->catfile(File::Spec->catfile(".", "foo"), "bar");
File::Spec->catfile("./foo", "bar");
```

For a library that supposed to standardize this stuff, why is my `./` gone? Is there a reason for this behavior?

Just weird to have this returned,

```
CP-JobApp/t/lib/Testing.pm
CP-JobApp/t/pod.t
CP-JobApp/t/find.t
./h
./problem1.pl
```

Is it normal to post-process file names the module returns?

Comment: it calls catdir to concatenate all but the final arg, and catdir calls canonpath which "cleans up" . entries, double slashes, leading /.., and such

Comment: @ysth But why "clean up" the `./` on only files **not** in the root? That seems like a major inconsistency.

Comment: `File::Spec->catfile(File::Spec->catfile(".", "foo"), "bar");` makes no sense. Should be `File::Spec->catfile(File::Spec->catdir(".", "foo"), "bar");` or `File::Spec->catfile(".", "foo", "bar");`

Comment: @EvanCarroll don't know what you mean by "not in the root"; what's an example of "in the root"?

Comment: @ysth, They mean the base directory. More specifically, they mean a base of directory of `.`. The question is in the comments ask why `./file` isn't canonized to `file`.

Comment: Or why not canonize all things with the `./` prefix (there isn't a standard that I know that says an initial `./` is incorrect). It's more about the inconsistency.

Comment: No way. To canonize means to clean up. Adding noise is the opposite of that

Comment: @ikegami I don't read "canonicalization" as "cleaning up". It's supposed to be standardizing which is why this bizarre. That said, the "Remove Dot Segments" algorithm in the W3C XML canonicalization says to remove `./` the `./foo` and I have no resistance to change either way.

Comment: To canonize is to  transform into the normal ("canon") form, which is a clean form for display. This includes getting rid of extraneous junk (e.g `./` in paths). (On systems like NTFS, it could also mean switching to the long name as capitalized on disk, though File::Spec doesn't do that.)

Comment: Ah.  catfile takes directory parts and a filename.  The directory is canonicalized, and . doesn't canonicalized to nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File::Spec::Unix canonizes the directory part of the path.

Why doesn't it canoninize the whole path (so that `catfile('.', 'file')` produces `file`)? No idea. This seems like an oversight to me. Feel free to file a bug report.